# How to obtain a matrix of size n*3(where n is the total number of pixels of an image) having R,G and B components of the image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to obtain a matrix consisting of only the R,G and B components of every pixel of an image. The cv2.imread function returns a 3 channel array. I wish to convert the 3d array into an array of size n*3 where 'n' must be the total number of pixels of the image and the 3 columns must contain the red, green and blue values at each pixel.

Comment: do you want them `[r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b ..... r,g,b]` or `[ r,r,r,r,r,...r,g,g,g,g,....,g,b,b,b,b,....,b]` or `[[r,..],[g...],[b,...]]` - what did you try and what is your problem wiht your code. Where _is_ your code?

Comment: I can't figure out a way to do it. I want them [r,g,b][r,g,b]....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reshape the array:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in color (its the default as well)
img = cv2.imread(r'somepath\2015-08-05 10.58.36.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )

print (img.shape)

c = img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],3))

print(c.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2048, 1536, 3)  # my original image
(3145728, 3)     # reshaped


for i in range(9):
    print(img[0][i])
    print(c[i])
```

Output:

```
[191 125  84]  # from img
[191 125  84]  # from c 
[191 125  84]  # etc.
[191 125  84]
[185 119  78]
[185 119  78]
[184 118  77]
[184 118  77]
[188 122  81]
[188 122  81]
[189 123  82]
[189 123  82]
[188 122  81]
[188 122  81]
[190 124  83]
[190 124  83]
[190 126  85]
[190 126  85]
```

BGR

For each color, #0 is Blue, #1 is Green, #2 is Red.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I exactly wanted.

Comment: @JaiVora just be aware its BGR nor RGB - cv2 is weird that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are after (note that `cv2.imread` reads the image as BGR, so `np.flip(j,1)` converts the pixel order to RGB):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread(r'Path to Image')

pixels = [np.flip(j, 1) for j in [i for i in img]]
```